# Using Int PK instead of GUID for large table data sets

Tags: asp.net

On every good team I've workd on, we've (the leads and architects) stayed away from utilizing GUIDs for authentication and userIDs just because they are especially for an e-commerce site very under-performing in terms of performance vs. just a PK Int.  At least that was the consensus in addition to a pain to work with.

How can I use Int Ids but for large data sets and still get past the uniqueness issue (running out of unique Ids) without using GUIDs?

Comment: Do you plan on running out of 2.1b numbers? Can always go bigint/int64, which has a max size of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: probably not going to run out...I just like plain Ids...easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) for your options. Also, you should check if storing all those records inside single table is a good option for you. Perhaps you should think about table [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic1)?